# Check if a word is a part of another word

Tags: string, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two columns with some text:

| text_1 | text_2 |
| --- | --- |
| astro lumen cosm planet | microcosm astronomy planet magnitude |

I need to remove a word from column `text_1` if this word occurs in `text_2` column (i.e., is a complete duplicate) or is a **part** of some word in `text_2` column.

Desired output:

| text_1 | text_2 |
| --- | --- |
| lumen | microcosm astronomy planet magnitude |

How can I do this in PostgreSQL and/or PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the first column into array of words then filter the array using [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html) function like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("astro lumen cosm planet", "microcosm astronomy planet magnitude")],
    ["text_1", "text_2"]
)

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "text_1",
    F.array_join(
        F.filter(F.split("text_1", "\\s+"), lambda x: ~F.col("text_2").contains(x)),
        " "
    )
)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+------+------------------------------------+
#|text_1|text_2                              |
#+------+------------------------------------+
#|lumen |microcosm astronomy planet magnitude|
#+------+------------------------------------+
```

Note that for spark before 3.1+, you need to use `expr` for higher order function [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#filter)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in SQL:

```
WITH data AS (
   SELECT 'astro lumen cosm planet' AS needles,
          'microcosm astronomy planet magnitude' AS haystack
)
SELECT string_agg(needle.n, ' ')
FROM data
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_split_to_table(data.needles, ' +') AS needle(n)
WHERE strpos(data.haystack, needle.n) = 0;

 string_agg 
════════════
 lumen
(1 row)
```